# How to publish open graph stories One to One - Without Object Title?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm having troubles trying to publish open graph stories.

I created my action and object, but I can just publish stories like One to One - With Object Title and I want Without Object Title. How can I do this?

I also want to publish this action without an image, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

We are having the opposite issue. We are publishing stories with an object title but they are always showing w/o an object title.

Comment: How did you set up your app at facebook developers app settings?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. We are using open graph to publish the story. The story is approved but whenever we publish a story for a user, it always appears without a title.